# Add tick data from kucoin to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I receive tick from kucoins'api and i would like to store them using symbol, price and time

```
async def websocketConnect():
    async def event(msg):
        tick = pd.DataFrame([{"symbol": msg['subject'], "price": msg['data']['price'], "timestamp": msg['data']['time']}])

        allTicks.append(tick, ignore_index=True)

        print(allTicks)
```

I append tick to allTicks but here is the result :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [symbol, price, timestamp]
Index: []
```

Comment: `append` isn't in-place in pandas, it returns a new frame.

Comment: Should i use something else ?

Comment: Kind of, yes. `allTicks = allTicks.append(tick, ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: I feel so stupid, thanks

Comment: No need to feel like that, this might happen to many people. Python lists' `append` is in-place, so one might expect this is, too, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Neither :

```
async def websocketConnect():
        async def event(msg):
            tick = pd.DataFrame([{"symbol": msg['subject'], "price": msg['data']['price'], "timestamp": msg['data']['time']}])
    
            allTicks = allTicks.append(tick, ignore_index=True)
    
            print(allTicks)
```